# no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries on docker windows server 2016

Tags: docker

I am using windows server 2016. I have installed docker using MS doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server

When I pull the node image from the dockerHub I am facing the below error.

```
    PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker pull node
    Using default tag: latest
    latest: Pulling from library/node

   no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries
```

Can someone help how I can use these docker images (alpine, Nginx, ubuntu) in windows server 2016?

My docker version and info:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.0-dev
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   8e92415
 Built:        Thu May 26 17:08:34 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      20.10.9
 API version:  1.41
 Go version:   go1.16.12m2
 Git commit:   9b96ce992b
 Built:        12/21/2021 21:33:06
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64


PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 20.10.9
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Execution Driver: <not supported>
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.4046.amd64fre.rs1_release.201028-1803)
Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.4046)
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 8 GiB
Name: EC2XXXXXXXXXXX
ID: XXXX:XXXX:XXX
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
PS C:\Users\Administrator
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Docker container uses the OS kernel to run. Your problem is that the `node` container requires a Linux kernel and you are using a Windows NT kernel.

On Windows versions < 1709, you cannot use: WSL, Hyper-V, LinuxKit, Docker Desktop to solve the problem.

Working method, but with a **big loss of performance**:

1. Install [Qemu](https://www.qemu.org/download/#windows), VMware or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
2. Install in virtual machine any Linux server distribution (e.g. [Debian](https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/)).
3. Then install Docker and Docker Compose: `apt install -y docker docker.io docker-compose`.
4. Now you can run any Linux container:)

Comment: Hi @lcomrde , Thanks for answering my question.  The link you have provided is for windows server 2016? because in the Prerequisites i am seeing that,  this setup supports only Windows 10 Professional, Windows 10 Enterprise, or Windows Server 2019 version 1809 or later. For me, i am using WS2016.

Comment: Quote from the documentation:
*Docker has been able to run Linux containers on Windows desktop since it was first released in 2016 (before Hyper-V isolation or Linux containers on Windows were available) using a [LinuxKit](https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit) based virtual machine running on Hyper-V.*

Comment: hi sorry for asking this.  I am a little bit confused here.  As you said, due to performance loss I am not using it for project deployment.  But for my learning purpose, is that possible to run a Linux-based image like (Nginx, node, alpine) on my windows server  2016 using docker? if that is possible means pls share with me some good links or docs. because I am seeing a lot of deprecated links over the internet.

Comment: Oops... I thought `Windows Server 2016 1607` and `Windows Server 2016 1709` were the same operating system. **I corrected my answer, please read it again:)**

Answer (score 0):

This is the inverse of the tip provided on the [second page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/run-your-first-container). You need to right click on the docker icon and switch to running Linux containers to be able to run these images since they do not have a Windows image available.

From my experience, Windows images are a small minority of the container images available, and most users switch to running Linux images, even on Windows servers, unless they have a use case that cannot be migrated. As a bonus, the Linux images are much smaller and more portable (not tied to specific versions of Windows).