# How to run linux docker image in windows server 2016?

Tags: docker

I have installed docker in windows server 2016 using [microsoft documention.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server#tabpanel_1_Windows-Server)

I need to create a docker image using docker file. Tried with the sample dockerfile and i am facing the error.

- why linux container not supporting in the docker windows 2016 server.
  Do i need to install any additional step for linux container?

This is my docker file:

```
FROM node:10.15.3  
CMD ["echo", "Welcome"]
```

**The error I am facing:**

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.56kB
Step 1/2 : FROM node:10.15.3
10.15.3: Pulling from library/node
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries
```

Docker version:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>docker version
Client: Mirantis Container Runtime
 Version:           20.10.9
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.12m2
 Git commit:        591094d
 Built:             12/21/2021 21:34:30
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Mirantis Container Runtime
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.9
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.16.12m2
  Git commit:       9b96ce992b
  Built:            12/21/2021 21:33:06
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Docker Info:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  cluster: Manage Mirantis Container Cloud clusters (Mirantis Inc., v1.9.0)
  registry: Manage Docker registries (Docker Inc., 0.1.0)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 20.10.9
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter
  Windows:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: process
 Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.4046.amd64fre.rs1_release.201028-1803)
 Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.4046)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 16GiB
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: seems the base image `node:10.15.3` is incompatible with docker for windows. you may search *node docker windows*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

Comment: the problem is windows 2016 server dont have the docker whale icon on the system tray. so i cant switch to linux container in windows. also i have tried with this docker image  (https://hub.docker.com/r/stefanscherer/node-windows/) still same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your windows server version. you are using windows server 2016 **(1607 version)**. since you are using the 1607 version you cant use WSL, Hyper-V, LinuxKit, Docker Desktop to run the Linux container image i.e (node, alpine, Nginx, etc..)

Please refer this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71567101/no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries-on-docker-wi). you will find the solution.